# how can I get a full line of code from an xml file while parsing it using sax parser in python

Tags: python-2.7

how can I get a full line of code from an xml file while parsing it using sax parser in python. I found that there is an easy way to do it using DOM Parser but is there any workaround so that I can get it using SAX Parser.

Comment: what have you tried so far? have a look at [ask]